# Create a text file using user input from a batch file

Tags: batch

Is it possible to write a batch file that will create a popup window for the user to input some specific information, and place that information into a text file? The text file should already have some text in it but I just want a couple lines to have input from the user. This is what the text file should look like:

```
PARTSN="USER INPUT1"
PART=blahblah
WORKSTATION=blahblah
USERID="USER INPUT2"
SIZE=blahblah
```

Where it says `"USER INPUT1,2"` is where I want the information from the user placed.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set /p` to ask the user for input:

```
set /p SomeVar=What is your favourite colour? 
echo Favourite colour: %SomeVar%
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This will ask for four values, then print the resulting file to the desktop. It will append to the same file everytime you run this, unless you delete the file.

```
@echo off
set Output="%USERPROFILE%\desktop"

set /p VarOne=Enter variable one value: 
set /p VarTwo=Enter variable two value: 
set /p VarThree=Enter variable three value: 
set /p VarFour=Enter variable four value: 

REM enter your desired output here
echo Variable One   = %VarOne% >> %Output%\test.txt
echo Variable Two   = %VarTwo% >> %Output%\test.txt
echo Variable Three = %VarThree% >> %Output%\test.txt
echo Variable Four  = %VarFour% >> %Output%\test.txt

echo.
echo File has been placed %Output%
pause
```